# Von Eigennamen abgeleitete Inhaltswörter

Tags: proper-noun, word-formation

Aus dem Englischen kennt man den Ausdruck *serendipity* für einen glücklichen Zufallsfund, den Horace Walpole von *Serendip*, einer alten Bezeichnung für das heutige Sri Lanka, abgeleitet hat. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serendipit%C3%A4t))

Desweiteren vielleicht *malaproprism* nach der Figur der Mrs. Malaprop in einem Theaterstück von 1775 für die unabsichtliche unangemessene Verwendung insbesondere von schwierigen Wörtern. Dieses Beispiel ist etwas fragwürdig, da es sich bei *Malaprop* um einen sprechenden Namen, abgeleitet von frz. *mal à propos* "unangemessen" handelt. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropismus))

In der Comedyserie *Community* gibt es *to britta* "vermasseln, verkorksen" als Gelegenheitsbildung. ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qS85kvq8Xo))

Die Beispiele legen nahe, daß das Englische für solche Bildungen offen ist. **Welche Beispiele für die Ableitung von Inhaltswörtern aus Eigennamen gibt es im Deutschen?**

Das Verb *merkeln* mit der Bedeutung "wichtige Entscheidungen aufschieben", Kandidat für das Jugendwort des Jahres 2015, hat sich wohl nie richtig etabliert.

Ein Beispiel aus der Umgangssprache wäre die Verwendung von *Horst* als Pejorativ, was sogar Erwähnung in der [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_(Vorname)) findet.

Comment: Pejorativ verwendete Vornamen gibt es mehrere: Kevin, Chantal ([Wikipedia: Kevinismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevinismus)), Detlev, Hugo, Olaf, Egon

Comment: Ich biete noch *Bernd* für *anonymous*.

Comment: @Janka Also im Sinn von *Niemand*?

Comment: Ja. *Bernd* ist ein Name, den keiner mehr trägt. Oder jeder tragen könnte. Ein Allerweltsname von gestern. Das hat sich in deutschsprachigen <s>Image</s>Trollboards so eingebürgert.

Comment: May I add that the latest such word in English is ***maying*** - for asking several times to same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auf die Schnelle fallen mir nur Begriffe ein, die international üblich sind, also nicht spezifisch nur für die deutsche Sprache:

- **boykottieren, Boykott**
  organisiertes strafweises Ausschließen einer Organisation durch eine Gruppe
  [Charles Cunningham Boycott](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Cunningham_Boycott)
- **Sandwich**
  Zwischenmahlzeit
  [John Montagu, 4. Earl of Sandwich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Montagu,_4._Earl_of_Sandwich)
- **Silhouette**
  Umriss, Schattenbild
  [Étienne de Silhouette](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tienne_de_Silhouette)
- **Schrapnell**
  Mit Kugel gefüllte Granate
  [Henry Shrapnel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Shrapnel)
- **Spenzer**
  kurze Jacke
  [George Spencer, 2. Earl Spencer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Spencer,_2._Earl_Spencer)
- **lynchen, Lynchjustiz**
  wiederrechtliche Bestrafung vermeintlicher Straftäter
  Der Name geht auf eine Person zurück, deren Nachname *»Lynch«* lautet, dafür kommen aber vier verschiedene Personen in Frage, siehe [Wikipedia: Lynchjustiz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynchjustiz#Begriffsherkunft)
- **morsen**
  Einfache binäre Datenübertragungsmethode für Buchstaben und Ziffern.
  [Samuel F. B. Morse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_F._B._Morse)
- **galvanisieren**
  elektrochemisches Verfahren um Metallschichten auf ein Werkstück aufzubringen
  [Luigi Galvani](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Galvani)
- **Kalaschnikow**
  Maschinengewehr
  [Michail Timofejewitsch Kalaschnikow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michail_Timofejewitsch_Kalaschnikow)
- **Glock**
  Pistole
  [Gaston Glock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Glock)
- **pasteurisieren**
  Haltbarmachen durch Erhitzen
  [Louis Pasteur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Pasteur)
- **Axel**
  Sprung im Eiskunstlauf
  [Axel Paulsen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axel_Paulsen)
- **Cardigan**
  Strickjacke
  [James Brudenell, 7. Earl of Cardigan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Brudenell,_7._Earl_of_Cardigan)

Mir fallen nur zwei Begriffe ein, die meines Wissens nur im deutschsprachigen Raum verwendet werden:

- **röntgen**
  Durchleuchten mit hochenergetischen elektromagnetischen Strahlen (X-ray)
  [Wilhelm Conrad Röntgen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Conrad_R%C3%B6ntgen)
- **verballhornen**
  einen bekannten Begriff entstellen
  [Johann Balhorn der Jüngere](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Balhorn_der_J%C3%BCngere)

Daneben gibt es dann natürlich noch Namen für Gegenstände, die aus der Verbindung eines Personennamens und eines anderen Bestandteils bestehen: Bowiemesser, Bunsenbrenner, Dieselmotor, Fischerdübel, Litfaßsäule, Martinshorn, Stalinorgel, Stanleymesser usw.

Viele chemische Elemente sind nach Personen benannt (z.B. Einsteinium, Curium, Bohrium, Fermium, Mendelevium, Nobelium)

Auch einige geographische Begriffe sind von Personennamen abgeleitet (z.B. Amerika, Karlsruhe, Philippinen)

Comment: Das ist doch eine beeindruckend lange Liste. Sehr oft geht es wohl um Erfindungen oder technische Verfahren. Daran hatte ich beim Verfassen der Frage gar nicht gedacht. *Verballhornen* ist natürlich wunderbar.

Comment: "Röntgen" wird auch im Schwedischen genau so wie im Deutschen verwendet. Wir flektieren das Wort aber nach schwedischer Art: "röntga, röntgade, röntgat",

Comment: Aus dem Englischen: *shanghaien*

Comment: @Beta: Hast du _»[wallraffa](https://www.welt.de/debatte/kommentare/article106212495/Das-Wallraffen-und-die-Wahrheit.html)«_ im Schwedischen schon mal gehört? Oder wird es gar heute noch verwendet?

Comment: @Pollitzer ja das Wort wird immernoch verwendet, es hatte aber seine größte Verwendung in den 70er und den 80er Jahren. Manche Junge wissen aber nicht was dabei gemeint worden ist

Comment: Und *Schrapnelle* (hässliche Frau). Ist vielleicht Mundart.

Comment: Analog zu Axel gibt es wohl noch Rittberger (ist übrigens nur im deutschen Sprachraum gebräuchlich) und Salchow. Ich nehme an, es wird nach Personennamen gesucht, sonst gibt es noch viel mehr: Telemark, Krefelder, Hamburger, usw.

Comment: Röntgen wird im Niederländischen auch benutzt.

Comment: Ich finde die Auflistung von Industrieprodukten, die nach ihren Erfindern benannt sind, unbefriedigend. Diese Liste lässt sich ja endlos erweitern. Was ist mit *Daimler*? Sogar *Audi* (lateinische Form des Familiennamens *Horch*, als Imperativ), dann etliche Produkt- und Firmennamen aus den 50er Jahren, die aus Personennamen zusammengezogen wurden wie *Robbe* (Modellbau-Bedarf, Firmengründer Robert Becker), und so weiter. Dann ganze Firmen, die einfach so heißen, wie ihre Gründer: Schießer, Bosch, Siemens, Braun, Philips, Toyota, Porsche... alles das sollte man hier einfach ausschließen.

Comment: Trotzdem noch zur Ergänzung der (soeben kritisierten) Liste: ***Rittberger*** - eine Figur im Eiskunstlauf, benannt nach einem Eiskunstläufer.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann An die Fälle, bei denen aus einem Personen- ein Produkt- oder Firmenname wurde, habe ich bei der Formulierung der Frage nicht gedacht. Mich interessieren tatsächlich eher Fälle, bei denen das abgeleitete Wort nicht den Charakter eines Namens hat. Aber die Abgrenzung ist gar nicht so leicht: Was ist mit dem Monat *August*, dem *Freitag*, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Hier noch ein paar Worte aus [Röntgen – Verben aus Personennamen](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/5214/file/Donalies_Roentgen_2016_3.pdf) von Elke Donalies aus dem ids Sprachreport, wobei die letzten spezifisch deutsch sind:

- fletscher ‘gründlich kauen’ (nach dem amerikanischen Laienmediziner Fletcher)
- galvanisieren ‘durch Elektrolyse mit einer dünnen Metallschicht überziehen’ (nach dem italienischen Anatom Galvani)
- lumbecken ‘ohne Fadenheftung als Buch binden’ (nach dem deutschen Erfinder Lumbeck)
- lynchen (nach dem amerikanischen Richter Lynch)
- mensendiecken ‘eine bestimmte Art von Gymnastik betreiben’ (nach der niederländisch-amerikanischen Gymnastiklehrerin Mensendieck)
- merzerisieren ‘mit einem bestimmten Verfahren Baumwolle seidenglänzend machen’ (nach dem englischen Industriellen Mercer)
- morsen (nach dem amerikanischen Erfinder Morse)
- pasteurisieren (nach dem französischen Chemiker Pasteur)
- aphrodisieren (nach der griechischen Liebesgöttin Aphrodite)
- bezirzen (nach der griechisch-mythologischen Zauberin Cirze)
- fuggern ‘Handel treiben’ (nach dem schwäbischen Kaufmannsgeschlecht)
- fringsen (nach dem Kölner Kardinal Frings, der den Überlebensdiebstahl der Nachkriegszeit empathisch sah): „fringsen stand fortan für die abgesegnete, illegale Beschaffung von Lebensmitteln und Heizmaterial“ (Anderson 1997, S. 22)
- kneippen ‘kuren, eine Kneippkur machen’ (nach dem heilkundigen Pfarrer Kneipp)
- verballhornen (nach dem Lübecker Drucker Ballhorn)

Außerdem fällt mir noch ein:

- [riestern](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/riestern) (für eine Riester-Rente sparen)
- [hartzen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hartzen) (von Hartz IV leben)
- [müllern](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/sport/fussball-muellern-wie-messi-1.3823742) (bezogen auf einen dänischen Gymnastik-Trainer oder auf verschiedene deutsche Fußballspieler)

Answer (score 3):

Zahlreiche physikalische Einheiten entstammen Eigennamen. Ich zähle ein paar auf:

- Celsius, Kelvin, Fahrenheit, Rankine
- Siemens, Ohm
- Ampere, Volt, Coulomb, Franklin, Farad
- Watt, Joule
- Tesla, Gauß, Oerstedt
- Weber, Maxwell, Henry, Gilbert
- Hertz
- Sievert, Röntgen, Gray
- Curie, Becquerel
- Ångström
- Newton
- Stokes
- Pascal
- ...

Comment: Im Nachhinein merke ich, daß die Abgrenzung zwischen Eigennamen und Inhaltsworten gar nicht so einfach ist. Sind die genannten Begriffe nur Namen für Einheiten? Und sind *Stunde, Mai* von anderer Art oder nicht? Das geht dann wahrscheinlich in Richtung einer neuen Frage.

Comment: Die genannten Begriffe sind Namen für physikalische Einheiten. Auch »Stunde« ist eine physikalische Einheit, denn man kann Zeit auch in dieser Einheit messen. »Mai« ist aber etwas anderes. Das ist der Name eines ganz bestimmten Monats. Mit *Mai* kann man nichts messen. Richtig: Der Vorgang dauert 5 *Stunden*. Auch richtig: Die Reise dauert 7 *Monate*. Abr falsch: Die Reise dauert 7 *Mai*.

Answer (score 2):

Mein Synonymwörterbuch von 1997 gibt (nach [Günter Wallraff](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnter_Wallraff))

> wallraffen

als **»in einer mit persönlicher Gefahr verbundenen Weise nachforschen«** an. Dieses Wort habe ich zwar gekannt, es ist aber eher ein Exot, obwohl es offenbar sogar ins Ausland ging. [Hier](https://www.welt.de/debatte/kommentare/article106212495/Das-Wallraffen-und-die-Wahrheit.html) gibt es einen Artikel dazu.

[image]

Inzwischen noch gefunden:

> - [Gustav Stresemann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Stresemann): der [Stresemann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stresemann_(Anzug)) (Anzug)
> - [Friedrich Louis Dobermann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Louis_Dobermann): der [Dobermann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobermann) (Hund)
> - [Friedrich von Drais](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_von_Drais): die [Draisine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draisine_(Laufmaschine)) (Laufrad)

Comment: Das scheint wie bei *merkeln* zu sein: Ein Wort, das kurz Begeisterung auslöst, aber dann schnell wieder verschwindet.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Es sieht danach aus. Zumindest im Inland; ob es im Ausland noch lebendiger ist, kann ich nicht sagen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Dass nun ausgerechnet "merkeln" *Begeisterung* auslösen soll, glaube ich jetzt nicht, aber ich stimme dir zu und vermute, dass das Wort schon rein inhaltlich in absehbarer Zeit überholt sein wird (und dann vermutlich maximal noch zwei oder drei Legislaturperioden zu Vergleichszwecken verwendet wird).

Answer (score 1):

Dass unserem Freund Hubert aus Österreich ausgerechnet das

> Mosern

nicht eingefallen ist, verblüfft mich. So weit ich weiß, geht es zurück auf den Schauspieler Hans Moser (bürgerlich Johann Julier, 1880-1964) und seinen im Wiener Dialekt vorgetragenen Ausdruck allgemeiner oder auch anlassspezifischer Unzufriedenheit.

Comment: Das Verb *mosern* scheint älter zu sein als der Schauspieler. Vermutlich also Volksetymologie.

Comment: @DavidVogt  Hast du Genaueres zum Mosern als prähansmoserisches Verbum?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/mosern Pfeifer sagt 18. Jahrhundert.